# Why are the biguery.tables.list and bigquery.tables.get permissions not part of the 'Owner' role?

Tags: google-bigquery

Why are the biguery.tables.list and bigquery.tables.get permissions not part of the 'Owner' role ?
I tried to run a query on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA_VIEWS and got permission denied even though I am an Owner of the Project - discovered the 2 permissions required are not granted to the Owner role so have had to set up a custom role to include them, this seems crazy - as an Owner surely you should be able to do anything ?  Is this a bug ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a bug. If you take a look at the "[Basic role definitions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles#basic)" section at the "[Understanding roles](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-roles)" page, there is a "Note" in the `roles/editor` row, which says:

> While the roles/editor role contains permissions to create and delete resources for most Google Cloud services, it does not contain permissions to perform all actions for all services.

`roles/owner` contains all the permission of the `roles/editor` so the message above applies to this basic role too. I checked the `roles/owner` permissions with the following command

```
gcloud iam roles describe  roles/owner
```

and there indeed isn't the `bigquery.tables.get` or `bigquery.table.list` role.

If you believe it is a bug and should be fixed, I advise creating a feature request on the [Issue Tracker for BigQuery](https://issuetracker.google.com/savedsearches/559654).